# Graph Send.Mail works at first, then gives CORS error

Tags: cors, microsoft-graph-api, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6.0 MVC app that uses Microsoft Graph for sending email as the logged in user. I'm using Microsoft Identity to log the user in and implement MFA. At first, it all works as expected. The user can log in, send emails no problem. However, at some point (no clear "point") the emailing sending function will stop working for that user and a CORS error will be recorded in the console. It continues to work for other logged-in users, so its user-specific. The console error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXX' (redirected from [https://www.myemailsendingsite.com/GraphEmail/SendEmail'](https://www.myemailsendingsite.com/GraphEmail/SendEmail%27)) from origin 'https://www.myemailsendingsite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I can find a lot of references to similar errors, but all of them are the situation where it never works at all and I'm stumped. I don't understand why it works at first and then, seemingly at random, it will just not anymore. The only solution right now, is for the user to close their browser (not the tab) and return to the site and login again. I'm thinking there is some sort of timeout or expiry happening, but I don't know why that would return this particular error. If changes are needed in Azure AD, I don't have access, so I'd need to be able to explain to the admin exactly what needs to be done.

Here is the relevant JS and C#:

Javascript function:

```
function sendEmail() {

    if ($("#sendEmailForm").valid()) {
        var formData = new FormData($("#sendEmailForm").get(0));

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.onload = function () {
            if (ajax.status >= 300) {
                toastr.error("Error!");
                console.log(ajax.responseText);
            }
            else {
                toastr.success("Email sent!");
                dt.ajax.reload();
            }
        };
        ajax.open("POST", "/GraphEmail/SendEmail", true);
        ajax.send(formData);
    }
}
```

C# Controller (`Email` is my own custom object):

```
public class GraphEmailController : Controller
{
    private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

    public GraphEmailController(IConfiguration configuration,
                        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
    {
        _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmail(Email email)
    {
        string[] toAddresses = email.ToEmail.Split(";", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string[] ccAddresses;
        List<Recipient> toRecipients = new();
        List<Recipient> ccRecipients = new();

        Message message = new Message();

        foreach (string address in toAddresses)
            toRecipients.Add(new Recipient { 
                EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { 
                    Address = address.Replace(" ", "") 
                } 
            });

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email.CcEmail))
        {
            ccAddresses = email.CcEmail.Split(";", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (string address in ccAddresses)
                ccRecipients.Add(new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = address.Replace(" ", "")
                    }
                });
        }

        message.ToRecipients = toRecipients;
        message.CcRecipients = ccRecipients;
        message.Subject = email.Subject;
        message.Body = new ItemBody
        {
            Content = email.Body,
            ContentType = BodyType.Html
        };

        if (email.SendTime != null)
        {
            message.SingleValueExtendedProperties = new MessageSingleValueExtendedPropertiesCollectionPage();
            message.SingleValueExtendedProperties.Add(new SingleValueLegacyExtendedProperty()
            {
                Id = "SystemTime 0x3FEF",
                Value = email.SendTime?.AddHours(DateTime.UtcNow.Hour - DateTime.Now.Hour).ToString("o")
            });
        }

        if (email.Attachments != null)
        {

            MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage attachments = new MessageAttachmentsCollectionPage();

            foreach (IFormFile file in email.Attachments)
            {
                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(ms);
                        var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                        string s = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);

                        attachments.Add(new FileAttachment()
                        {
                            ContentBytes = fileBytes,
                            Name = file.FileName
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            message.Attachments = attachments;
        }

        await _graphServiceClient.Me
            .SendMail(message, true)
            .Request()
            .PostAsync();

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email.RunsheetEntryIds))
        {
            List<int> runsheetEntryIds = email.RunsheetEntryIds.Split("&rsIds=", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();

            UpdateStatusAfterEmail(email.IsReminder, runsheetEntryIds);
        }

        return Ok();

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your description sounds as if you first make a logon flow, sending your users to microsoftonline.com in order to establish a session with https://www.myemailsendingsite.com. Then your function `sendEmail` makes successful requests that are authenticated with a session cookie.

Could it be that, after a while, the session (cookie) expires so that your server attempts another logon flow? Only that, this time, the request is an XMLHttpRequest that cannot be redirected to the microsoftonline.com origin. (Whereas the initial logon flow happened visibly, in a browser tab, with no cross-origin issues.)

When called via XMLHttpRequest without a valid session, your server should not redirect to microsoftonline.com, but instead send a special response that causes your app to repeat the logon flow visibly (in another browser tab, for example).

Comment: Interesting. Yes, that might be it, but when I look at the cookies for the site, the only ones created end on "browsing session", but this problem occurs even during the same session. Can a session cookie expire without closing the browser?

Comment: Perhaps the session on your .NET server has a shorter lifetime, even if the cookie is still valid?

Comment: It could be. I don't have access to check, but I'll reach out to our admin and see if they can help with that. Thanks!